# Working with existing LVM Partitions

Tags: ubuntu, partition, lvm, fdisk

Im using Ubuntu 20.02 LTS on a virtual machine. Recently the virtual disk was extended. My disk setup looks like:

```
lshw -class disk -short

    H/W path        Device     Class      Description
    =================================================
    /0/100/4/0      /dev/vda   disk       128GB Virtual I/O device
    
fdisk -l
    Disk /dev/vda: 120 GiB, 128849018880 bytes, 251658240 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: dos
    Disk identifier: 0x0000ba80
    
    Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
    /dev/vda1  *      2048   499711   497664  243M 83 Linux
    /dev/vda2       501758 41940991 41439234 19,8G  5 Extended
    /dev/vda5       501760 41940991 41439232 19,8G 8e Linux LVM
    
    
    Disk /dev/mapper/vsrv69xxx--vg-root: 19,25 GiB, 20661141504 bytes, 40353792 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    
    
    Disk /dev/mapper/vsrv69xxx--vg-swap_1: 508 MiB, 532676608 bytes, 1040384 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I want to extend the existing partions `vsrv69xxx--vg-swap` (fixed amount) and `vsrv69xxx--vg-root` (remaining free space) to use the maximum available space.

Theoretically I know how to extend the LVM partitions, but I don't know if it is necessary to extend vda2 first or leave it untouched.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Theoretically I know how to extend the LVM partitions, but I don't know if it is necessary to extend vda2 first or leave it untouched.

Your PV is on a logical partition (`vda5`) so yes, you need to resize the extended partition (`vda2`) first (this isn't really related to LVM, with logical partitions you always need to grow the extended partition to be able to use the free space outside it).

After that extend the PV partition and use `pvresize /dev/vda5` to resize the PV and then use `lvresize` to grow the two LVs.